How do I draw a PNG onto another PNG irrespective of the transparency?
Consider :
  Image1.Picture.LoadFromFile('pink_bars.png');
  black := TPngImage.Create();
  black.LoadFromFile('black.png');
  (Image1.Picture.Graphic as TPngImage).Canvas.Draw(0, 0, black);
  (Image1.Picture.Graphic as TPngImage).Modified := True;

Here, the contents of black.png won't appear where pink_bars.png has transparency. Which makes sense of course, but in this case I'd like the transparency info of black.png to be kept in the final result (for the portion of the image it is drawn upon, here it doesn't cover it all). I'm not sure of how I could do that short of overriding information in a loop pixel by pixel, manually.

Just looking once at the documentation would give you at least one idea: there's a separate method which instead of 3 arguments takes 4 for opacity. Have you even tried that? Also see existing answers.

@AmigoJack I've had past experiences with Embarcadero's documentation being plain wrong so I'm not in the habit of consulting it :) Additionally, yes I've tried it and no it doesn't work. This is because, as far as I can tell, TPngImage doesn't have a DrawTransparent function and in the base TGraphic function the Opacity is ignored.
